# what is the meaning of getting vain?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of **getting vain** in the following sentence?

> The alcoholic needs to be free to choose without our **getting vain** if
>   the message is used, or angry or discouraged if it is ignored.

This sentence is from one of AA pamphlets called "[A.A. in TREATMENT SETTINGS](http://www.aa.org/assets/en_US/p-27_AAinTF.pdf)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make much sense in everyday English... but I read it as **without getting big-headed or self-righteous**. Basically meaning that "we should not believe we are better than you". I think the issue  here is that this sentence can mean different things to different people so this is just my interpretation.

Edit: To expand on this, the word 'vain' usually means **to be in love with yourself**, which doesn't fit in with the sentence you quoted. This is why it is a difficult sentence to explain accurately.